# In the notification section, Autobiographer badge displays incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed

Just noticed this! Check the image below:

[image: Note the AskUbuntu and Meta notifications!]

If you look under 'Last 7 days' you can see how inside the brackets there is an attempt made to add quotation marks but it is instead shown as plain text. I think this is pretty self-explanatory, but if you want me to elaborate, please comment.

(If the image breaks for some reason, you can view it [here](http://www.mawersoft.co.uk/uploads/StackOverflow-Quot-Problem.png))

Comment: Your inline image works fine, but the backup link says "hotlinking not allowed".

Comment: @AndrewMedico Try refreshing the image. CloudFlare keeps tripping for some reason, I will disable it ASAP.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/241991/259693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next release.